# CSS3 transitions in chrome browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, css-transitions

I am using css3 transition animation for div element. need to animate the left and top  position of div element whenever hovering on specific points in chart. please refer our svg chart.

[image]

In chrome when animating div element, the div position always starts from top of the browser and then smooth transition  worked. every first time it starts from top of the browser  and the animate. but its working fine other browser. Please refer below div element code.

```
 $(tooltipdiv).css({
                'transition-property': 'left,top',
                '-moz-transition-property': 'left,top', /* Firefox 4 */
                '-webkit-transition-property': 'left,top', /* Safari and Chrome */
                '-o-transition-property': 'left,top',
                '-webkit-transition-timing-function':'linear',
                'transition-duration': series.toolTipOptions.duration,
                '-moz-transition-duration': series.toolTipOptions.duration, /* Firefox 4 */
                '-webkit-transition-duration': series.toolTipOptions.duration, /* Safari and Chrome */
                '-o-transition-duration': series.toolTipOptions.duration /* Opera */
            });
```

i don't want animation starts from top of the browser. how can i resolve this chrome browser ?

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: In your jQuery I see you setting the property, timing and duration but not the part were you set the top and left positions. Can you post that portion of your code?

Comment: did my answer help you at all?

Answer (score 0):

For this to work cross browser you must have your setup values `transition-property`, `transition-timing-function` and `transition-duration` in place before you make a change to `top` or `left`. Otherwise the transition will not fire.

`transition-property` and `transition-timing-function` both look like they could be setup in css instead of javascript because their values are not dynamic. So lets move those there. You should also provide 'start' values for `top` and `left` so those can go in CSS as well.

Next you need to set the `transition-duration` in css BEFORE you change `top` and `left`, luckily we can do this with simple jQuery chaining.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gt5s2/3/)**